# Подсчет количества цифр в строке

Tags: c++, c

Строка содержит произвольный текст. Вывести сколько раз в ней встречаются десятичные цифры (0-9). Найти две наиболее часто встречающиеся цифры.
Входные данные: строка `S`.

Я разработал такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char s[255] = { 0 };

    int num = 0;
    printf("Введите строку: ");
    gets(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < strlen(s); j++)
            if (s[i] == s[j]) 
                num++;
        for (int k = i +1; k < strlen(s); k++)
            if (s[k] == s[i]) s[k] = 0;
        if (s[i]!=0)
            printf("Символ %c встречается %d раз\n", s[i], num);
        num = 0;
    }
```

Но не понимаю, как его довести до выполнения поставленной задачи

Comment: Что значит "использовать 10 процессов"?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, не иначе,  как использовать  массив из 10 пайпов (на каждом повесить процесс) для подсчета количества конкретной цифры -)

Comment: Или под процессами имеются в виду потоки?...

Comment: Как и @Harry вернулся спросить, не подразумеваете ли вы случаем потоки. Процессы для такой задачи не имеют практической ценности ( как и потоки, но они ближе к ней ). Раз вам такое сказали сделать, то , возможно, вы сталкивались с таким понятием, как 'CreateThread' ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    //Работает корректно, при условии, что в массиве нет двух цифр встречающихся одинаковое колво раз!
    char *str = (char*)malloc(250 * sizeof(char)); //Выделяем память под массив
    printf("введите текст ");
    scanf("%s", str); //Записываем в строку

    char str2[] = "0123456789"; //Массив из 10 цифр от 0 до 9

    int n = strlen(str); //Узнаем длинну считанного массива

    int max1[2] = {-1, -1}; // Массив из двух элементов, хранит первую цифру. Первый элемент - цифра, второй - количество ее вхождений
    int max2[2] = {-1, -1}; // Вторая цифра

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(str[j] == str2[i]) count++; //Узнаем количество вхождений для каждой их цифры
        }

        if(max1[1] < count){ 
            max2[0] = max1[0];//Присваеваем второму максимальному числу предыдушее значение первого максимального числа
            max2[1] = max1[1];//

            max1[0] = i;      //Первому максимальному числу присваевавем новое значение
            max1[1] = count;  //
        }

        printf("Цифра %d встретилась %d раз\n\n", i, count);
    }

    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Цифра %d встретилась %d раз\n\n", max1[0], max1[1]);
    if(max2[1] == 0) printf("Второго максимальное число не существует\n");
    else printf("Цифра %d встретилась %d раз\n\n", max2[0], max2[1]);

    free(str); //Удаляем массив

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код соотвествующий заданию

Answer (score 1):

```
char s[255] = {0};
int m[10] = {0};
gets(s);
size_t n = strlen(s);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if(isdigit(s[i]))  // если этот символ является цифрой
        ++m[int(s[i] - '0')]; 
}
```

Допустим  прочитали символ `'1'`:
чтобы получить соответствующий целочисленный тип  символа `՛1՛`, нужно отнять символ `'0'`, т. е.  `int('1' - '0')` это то же  самое, что `int(1)`;

Увеличивая элемент массива  на 1, мы получаем `m[1] == 1`. Ну и так дальше..
 Т.е. в массиве индексы  будут соответствовать цифре, а значения количеству цифр.

Теперь нужно найти по какому индексу имеем две максимальных значений. Думаю остальную часть вы сами поймете

```
int max1 = 0, max2 = 0, index1 = 0, index2 = 0;;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {        
    if(m[i] > max1) {
        max2 = max1;
        index2 = index1;
        max1 = m[i];
        index1 = i;
    }
}
cout << index1 <<"  встречается  " << max1 <<" раз" <<endl
     <<index2 << "  встречается  " << max2 <<" раз";
```

Comment: если непонятно, добавлю  обьяснения

Comment: Не понятно. Раз вы ответили, то вы поняли. Что значит "использовать 10 процессов"?

Comment: Не понел, честно говоря, но пусть речь об операторах. У меня  же их кажется 10, т.е.  столько штук точка с запятой

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , добавьте объяснения пожалуйста

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ваш код не работает

Comment: @Кирилл Горбунов,  у меня работает, и почему вас не работает, это уже большой вопрос.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , я понял, у вас сразу выводится две максимально встречающиеся цифры, и сколько раз они встретились .Просто в задании написано"Вывести сколько раз в ней встречается цифра 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9", и я думаю, что если цифры нет, надо чтоб программа выводила соотвествующее сообщение

Comment: @Кирилл Горбунов, ну да,  это же соответствует требованию вашего задания

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , но ваше программа не воспринимает текст, хотя написано , что строка содержит произвольный текст, т.е. если я пишу буквы у меня вылезает  ошибка, как можно это исправить

Comment: Вы наверное  вводите на киррилице, а у вас не устанавливается  locale.  Вводите текс  на английском.  Причина у вас, у меня работает и должен работать, поскольку код тривиальный и не содержит ошибок. Отправьте ошибку, котроая у вас выскакивает